# Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays

Tags: server, graphics

me estoy conectando desde windows a un servidor linux que tien instalado ssh y activado x11forwarding, estaba trabajando normalment pero necesitada crear claves ssh y fue ahi caundo dejo de exportar la ventana grafica, he revisado toda la configuracion y no puedo encontrar el error,   cuando me inteneto conectar  mediante ssh  no se conecta  el servidor linux al Xming y por tanto no trae la interfaz grafica,  no se que debo cambiar para indicarle al servidor linux donde esta mi servidor xming (localhost:0.0) para que se conecte con esta y me permita  traer la interfaz... Gracias  a quien me quiera ayudar.. un abrazo a todos..